# Magento : How To Add Custom Form in New Shipment

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, forms, shipment

I include new form in New Shipment. So I can get it up later in Observer.
[image]

What is best way to include in table? 
I mean, should I include fields in `sales_flat_shipment`? 
How can I get them later in an Observer?

Currently I imagine through ovserver:

```
$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
$order = $shipment->getOrder();
echo $order->getField();
```

Thank you very much in advance.